# Spark: Technical terminology for reduce elements on the run-time?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce

In a word count example below:

```
(Hello,1)
(Hello,1)
(Hello,1)
(Hello,1)
(Hello,1)
```

The reducer function of Hadoop would collect all 5 elements with key "Hello", and then do the aggregation in the reducer function.

However, in Spark, it is actually reduces 2 elements each time. For example, it combines first and second (Hello,1) to (Hello,2), combines the third and forth (Hello,1) to (Hello,2) ... etc (of course, the real case might be in different order).

So is there a specific terminology to describe such computational method used in Spark? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't necessarily aggregate values that way.  How do you think a mapper in MapReduce works?

You can think of it like a hashmap.  If it sees the key is already in the hashmap, it increments the value, if not, it inserts the key into the hashmap and then initializes the value.

You cant add 1+1+1+1+1 with out adding 1+1,+1,+1,+1 in some combination, unless I'm forgetting some math.

Answer (score 1):

Spark does it in more functional way, so functional programming terminology should be applicable here.

```
rdd.reduce(_ + _)
```

is a **reduce** (fold/accumulate) **function**:

There are some good explanations available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csliu/archive/2009/11/10/map-reduce-in-functional-programming-parallel-processing-perspectives.aspx), so I'm just copy-pasting some of them:

> Fold (a.k.a. Reduce, Accumulate) is a higher order function that processes (using a combiner function) a list of elements in some order and build up a return value

Where "+" here is a **combiner function**:

> Combiner is a function that is applied to two elements and produces a result that can be combined using combiner with the remaining elements in the list.

Also there are more details available on fold functions in general and their application in functional programming [Fold (higher-order function)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))

Answer (score 0):

Terminology is same as Map Reduce. Only difference is unlike Map Reduce which only provides map and reduce functions to implement logic such as filtering, joins and aggregations, Spark have many out of the functions. For map in map reduce we have map, flatMap, filter etc in spark, for reduce in map reduce we have reduce, count, reduceByKey, countByKey, aggregateByKey, groupByKey, combineByKey etc in spark.

In Map Reduce you need to specify combiner class if you want to pre-aggregate on mapper side, in spark combiner is used if you use reduceByKey, aggregateByKey, combineByKey. If you do not want to use combiner, then you have to use groupByKey function.

Technical terminology is same in map reduce and spark for the topics you have asked. But it is different for topics such as distributed cache, in Spark it is called as broadcast. Also even though terminology is same there are subtle differences the way they operate.